# Apache - Protect Site for Testing

Tags: .htaccess

I mashed together the following .htaccess from the Web to allow access to a site from any user in our three locations AND for those outside those locations, I want an ability to use a password for access.

The following gives me a 500 Internal Server Error (for security, I replaced any number with an 'x' just for this question)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

<Files *>
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
AuthName "Enter password"
AuthType Basic
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
#Location 1
allow from xxx.x.xx
#Location 2
allow from xx.xxx
#Location 3
allow from xxx.xx
Require valid-user
Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Comment: Look in the Apache error log. There will be more details of the 500 error there.  Possibly the path to .htpasswd is incorrect.

Comment: sorry ... I should have thought to check the log ... thanks!